# Mediawiki file cache update after page edit

Tags: cache, mediawiki

I have implemented Mediawiki 1.35 on a dedicated server (24 core, 32GB RAM, RAID 1) to which I have root access.

The instance contains 21m+ articles, some of which are large and contain multiple script calls which cannot be further optimized. Consequently some page generation takes 30+ seconds to serve and sometimes the scripts timeout and exit incomplete which is obviously unacceptable from a UX perspective.

To mitigate the problem I enabled gzipped file caching as per [the official documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:File_cache) which works very well. By running multiple instances of [the official file cache generation script](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:RebuildFileCache.php) I can cache all the pages in 30 days (as a one off event). However, the default caching policy is to drop cached items on article edit (of course since the data is then stale), but *not regenerate a new cache file when the edit is submitted.* Therefore the first anonymous user to request the page has to wait for the caching to take place with the attendant problems I described above. The wiki has few editors but many anonymous readers.

I would like a solution to automatically regenerate a page's cache file on article edit. Is there a fairly simple way to hook into the end of the edit process and make a call to regenerate the cache file, or some other simple method? I prefer not to add the complication of (say) Varnish or other reverse proxy caching if possible but will consider any viable option.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You could try adjusting the `HtmlCacheUpdater` service, which handles these purges:

```
use MediaWiki\MediaWikiServices;

$wgHooks['MediaWikiServices'][] = function ( MediaWikiServices $services ) {
    $services->addServiceManipulator( 'HtmlCacheUpdater', function ( HtmlCacheUpdater $updater, MediaWikiServices $services ) {
        return new class() extends HtmlCacheUpdater {
            public function purgeTitleUrls( $pages, $flags = self::PURGE_PRESEND, array $unless = [] ) {
                $ret = parent::purgeTitleUrls( $pages, $flags, $unless );
                DeferredUpdates::addCallableUpdate( function () use ( $pages ) {
                    foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
                        $title = MediaWikiServices::getInstance()->getTitleFactory()->castFromPageReference( $page );
                        $article = new Article( $title );
                        $context = new DerivativeContext( $article->getContext() );
                        $output = new OutputPage( $context );
                        $output->disable();
                        $context->setOutput( $output );
                        $article->setContext( $context );
                        $article->view();
                    }
                } );
                return $ret;
            }
        };
    } );
};
```

Keep in mind that this is fragile, untested, and written for master - `castFromPageReference` is new in 1.37 so at least that part needs to be a bit different.